# Загрузка изображения через type=file

Tags: php, javascript, html

При загрузке изображения в БД через поле file вместо обычного пути выводится C:fakepathmail.png. При этом изображение не выводится. В интернете нашел, что это сделано для безопасности. Можно как-то решить эту проблему или есть какие-то альтернативные пути хранения изображения ? (изображения нужны для аватарки пользователя)

Comment: В чём конкретно заключается ваша проблема? Чем вам мешает фейковый путь?

Comment: Изображение не выводится.

Comment: Не выводится куда? Приложите код и подробно опишите задачу - сейчас на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой путь по соображениям безопасности сделан: `C:fakepath`.
Получить реальный путь нельзя, разве что через `0-day` браузера...

---

Вывести выбранное изображение можно и без пути, который, кстати, бесполезен, ведь доступа к ФС клиента у `JS` нет и слава Богу.

Предпросмотр картинки можно сделать так:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let file = document.querySelector('#file'),        // Выбираем нужные
      preview = document.querySelector('#preview');  // элементы
  
  file.addEventListener('change', e => { // При изменении input
    if(file.files.length === 0) // Если ничего не выбрано - выходим
      return;
    
    let f = file.files[0],     // Берём первый файл
        fr = new FileReader(); // Создаём объект чтения файлов
    
    // В свойсте type mime (что-то типа image/png)
    if(f.type.indexOf('image') === -1) // Если файл не является изображением - выходим
      return;
    
    fr.onload = e => {
      if(getComputedStyle(preview, null).display === 'none') // Если нужно - показываем img
        preview.style.display = 'block';
      
      preview.src = e.target.result; // В src будет что-то типа data:image/jpeg;base64,....
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(f); // Читаем blob выбранного файла
  });
});
```

```css
#preview{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='file' id='file' /><br /><br />
<img src='' id='preview' />
```

Comment: С предпросмотром понятно. А просто вывод ? Тоже самое я так понимаю ?

Comment: @Андрей, да, точно так же. Почитайте документацию, чтобы понимать что можно сделать (а можно сделать очень многое).

Comment: Я понял, всем спасибо за ответы. Буду разбираться.

Comment: @Андрей, пожалуйста, примите ответ (галочка под ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Включив **telepat_mode** я думаю, что вам нужно предпросмотр картинок сделать при загрузке. Я прав? Тогда рисуйте на canvas выбранный файл.

И если я правильно понял, то вот вам рабочий пример:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $("#imgInput").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
  });
});
```

```css
.input-file-row-1:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.input-file-row-1{
    display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 25px;
 position: relative;
}

html[xmlns] .input-file-row-1{
    display: block;
}

* html .input-file-row-1 {
    height: 1%;
}

.upload-file-container { 
 position: relative; 
 width: 100px; 
 height: 137px; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AeUEdJb.png) top center no-repeat;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 23px;
} 

.upload-file-container:first-child { 
 margin-left: 0;
} 

.upload-file-container > img {
 width: 93px;
 height: 93px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.upload-file-container-text{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #719d2b;
 line-height: 17px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 position: absolute; 
 left: 0; 
 bottom: 0; 
 width: 100px; 
 height: 35px;
}

.upload-file-container-text > span{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #719d2b;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.upload-file-container input  { 
 position: absolute; 
 left: 0; 
 bottom: 0; 
 font-size: 1px; 
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 border: none; 
 width: 70px; 
 height: 50px; 
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>
          
     <div class="input-file-row-1">
     
      <div class="upload-file-container">
       <img id="image" src="#" alt="" />      
       <div class="upload-file-container-text">
        <span>Add<br />photo</span>
        <input type="file" name="pic[]" class="photo" id="imgInput" />
       </div>
      </div>    
          
     </div>   
    </fieldset>
   </form>
```

Comment: Не, я имел в виду чтобы добавлять картинку в бд и потом выводить её у каждого пользователя как аватар.

Comment: Не вижу связи между fakepath и аватарами пользователя. Опишите задачу подробнее.

Comment: Ну пользователь при регистрации выбирает изображение через file. Это изображение добавляется в бд вместе с логином и паролем пользователя. И когда пользователь авторизируется на сайте, то это изображение из бд выводится как небольшая аватарка. И так у каждого пользователя в бд в поле image своё изображение, которое выводится в зависимости от того, какой пользователь зашел.

Comment: Вот хоть убей не пойму какая связь между полем input type='file' и выводом картинки из БД. Правильный ответ - никакой связи нет. Либо вы не понимаете схему работы, либо объяснить не можете правильно чего хотите, либо я тормоз (в последнем сомневаюсь).