# Как реализовать предосмотр фото в блоке, которое выбрано для загрузки, но еще не загружено

Tags: javascript, php, html

Пытался реализовать через JS но что то не могу понять почему не отображаеться

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById('photo').src = e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>
    <label for="photo">Загрузите новую фотографию пользователя:</label>
    <input type="file" id="photo" onchange="readURL(this);" name="photo">
  </p>
  <img id="photo" src="#">
  <p>
    <label for="cover_photo">Загрузите новый фон пользователя:</label>
    <input type="file" id="cover_photo" name="cover_photo">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Обновить">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Я использую filepond-plugin.

Comment: подскажи что да как) никогда с ним не сталкивался

Comment: Вот это попробуйте - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552499/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-type-file